# Stopping when a string has been found

Tags: batch-file, scripting, windows-server-2008

Hello StackOverflow community!

I have a BATCH question that has been plaguing me for a few days now:
I am trying to do a sting comparison (sounds simple) but I am doing it in this manner:
I have two Folders: SESSIONS and TARGETS.
Each of these folders has a ordinary text files that have been named after a server: Server1.txt, Server2.txt, Server3.txt, etc. Both directories have files with exactly the same names. The file names are important only because after reading them, I will know where to allocate the information that is contained in that file. Example:

> SESSIONS-->Server1.txt 
>   Word_one
>   Word_two
>   Word_three
>   word_seven
>
> TARGETS-->Server1.txt 
>   Word_one
>   Word_two
>   Word_seven

This is the code that i am using to traverse the Sessions and Targets folders:

```
FOR %%a in (%ses_dir%*.txt) DO (
FOR /F "TOKENS=1 DELIMS= " %%c in (%%a) DO (
    FOR %%f in (%targ_dir%*.txt) DO (
        FOR /F "TOKENS=1 DELIMS= " %%i in (%%f) DO (
            SET tmp_nam=%%~na

            IF %%c EQU %%i ( ECHO This is Connected)
            IF %%c NEQ %%i ( ECHO This is not Connected)
        )
    )
)
```

)

The above will print out all the sessions that are connected and all the sessions that are not connected. Essentially, this will output a LOT of redundant and useless information. I would like it to do the following: 
Every time it finds a string from the first file in the second file, Stop right there, and move onto the next string in the first file.
If it does not find the string from the first file in the second file. Echo "String not found" or something along those lines.

I have tried to be as descriptive as I could. Let me know if you have any additional questions.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Could you put the inner loop into a subroutine (somewhere else in the batch file, labelled e.g. inner_loop:  ) and then use "call" command to jump to it?  You could then use the "exit" command to break out of the sub and back to the main loop.

Answer (score 3):

This can be done with the built-in *associative arrays* of the Batch language:

```
@echo off &SETLOCAL
SET "sessionDir=SESSIONS"
SET "targetDir=TARGETS"

FOR %%a IN ("%sessionDir%\*.txt") DO (
    IF NOT EXIST "%targetDir%\%%~nxa" (
        ECHO "%%~nxa" NOT found IN "%targetDir%"
    ) ELSE (
        FOR /f "usebackqdelims=" %%b IN ("%%~fa") DO SET "$%%b=1"
        FOR /f "usebackqdelims=" %%b IN ("%targetDir%\%%~nxa") DO SET "#%%b=1"
        FOR /f "delims=$=" %%x IN ('set "$"') DO IF NOT DEFINED #%%x ECHO "%%x" missing IN "%targetDir%\%%~nxa"
        FOR /f "delims=#=" %%x IN ('set "#"') DO IF NOT DEFINED $%%x ECHO "%%x" missing IN "%%~fa"
    )
)
```

Please note: the `Word_` items can't have `=` signs, leading or trailing space.

Answer (score 1):

```
FOR %%a in (%ses_dir%*.txt) DO (
 FOR /F "TOKENS=1 DELIMS= " %%c in (%%a) DO (

  SET "tmp_nam="

  FOR /F "TOKENS=1 DELIMS= " %%i in (%targ_dir%%%~nxa) DO IF NOT DEFINED tmp_nam (
   IF %%c EQU %%i SET tmp_nam=%%~na
  )
  if defined tmp_nam (echo %%c connected) else (echo %%c not connected)
 )
)
```

This should, I believe, achieve your end.

`%%a` is set to each session's textfilename in turn.

`%%c` is set to each word from the textfile in `%%a` and `tmp_nam` is cleared

`%%i` is set to each word from the identical filename in the targets directory.

If a match is found, `tmp_nam` is set to something (it doesn't matter what, just not empty) The remainder of the comparisons to the remaining words in targets are skipped because `tmp_nam` is now defined.

Depending on whether a match was found or not, the word that matched + "(not) connected" is output. Could just as easily be `%%a` or both `%%c` and `%%a` if that floats your boat.

Now - if you mean that you want to say `%%a (not) connected` if `ANY ONE` word in the `session` is matched in `targets`, regardless,

```
FOR %%a in (%ses_dir%*.txt) DO (

 SET "tmp_nam="

 FOR /F "TOKENS=1 DELIMS= " %%c in (%%a) DO (
  FOR /F "TOKENS=1 DELIMS= " %%i in (%targ_dir%%%~nxa) DO IF NOT DEFINED tmp_nam (
   IF %%c EQU %%i SET tmp_nam=%%~na
  )
 )
 if defined tmp_nam (echo %%a connected) else (echo %%a not connected)
)
```

which is simply moving the reporting out one level.